# Angular + Rxjs operator - show loader if api not completed within 5 sec show toastr and hide loader

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Actually we are trying to avoid blocking user to do other operation while file upload in progress.

how can i show toastr and hide the loader if api is not completed with in 5 sec using rxjs in angular.

```js
uploadFile() {
  this.service.uploadFile(data)
    .pipe(
      //i am looking for operator which will wait 5 sec if and then hide the loader and show the toastr
    )
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.toastr.success('file uploaded successfully');
      this.loader.hide();
    })
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Question isn't exactly clear at the moment. Do you wish to cancel the ongoing request if isn't completed in 5 seconds? Or do you wish only to hide the loader and show a message if the request is taking longer than 5 seconds as a side effect?

Comment: thanks and i just need to hide and show the message @MichaelD

Answer (score 0):

you can create loading service like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LoadingService {
  private isLoading = new Subject<boolean>();
  constructor() {}

  public start(isHideImmediately: boolean = false) {
    this.isLoading.next(true);
    if (isHideImmediately) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.complete()
      }, 5000);
    }
  }
  public complete() {
    this.isLoading.next(false);
  }

  getLoadingStatus(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.isLoading.asObservable();
  }
}
```

and each time you call api you can start loading in start loading method by default after 5s loading is closed

your code:

```
uploadFile() {
  this.loadingService.start();
  this.service.uploadFile(data).subscribe(() => {
    this.toastr.success('file uploaded successfully');
    this.loadingService.complete();
  })
}
```

Comment: i am not looking to hide the loader after 5 sec.

Comment: i know you wanna hide your loader if api response take more than 5s yes? so in this service if api response under 5s loader closed by complete() method else after 5s loading closed by setTimeout isn't correct?

Comment: for other places also loader takes 5 sec to hide right ?

Comment: no no look at my answer we have another method with name complete() you can put it in subscribe part of your code like this -> "this.loadingService.complete()" so when your response is completed maybe in 1s or 200ms your loading will be closed but if take more than 5s like 7s loading will be closed by setTimeout in start method

Comment: start() {
    this.isLoading.next(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.complete()
    }, 5000);
  }

this will be executed for other api call and there also it will be hide automatically after 5 sec.

but i was expecting to only this specific api

Comment: so for this i edit answer and add boolean config for start method so for each api call you want work like this.loadingService.start(true) it means true for have hide loading immediately after 5s

Answer (score 0):

You could use plain JS `setTimeout()` to do something after a certain time. To not affect the ongoing API request, you could enclose it in RxJS `tap` operator. Also instead of hiding the loader otherwise in the subscription you could use `finalize` operator. That way the loader will also be closed if the request throws an error.

```js
uploadFile() {
  this.service.uploadFile(data).pipe(
    tap(_ => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.loader.hide();
        this.toastr.info('Uploading file');
      }, 5000);
    }),
    finalize(() => this.loader.hide())
  )
  .subscribe(() => {
    this.toastr.success('file uploaded successfully');
  })
}
```

But IMO hard coded time limits for loaders do not contribute to satisfactory interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the operator delay from rxjs:

```
import { delay } from "rxjs/operators";
    
uploadFile() {
  this.service.uploadFile(data)
    .pipe(delay(50000))
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.toastr.success('file uploaded successfully');
      this.loader.hide();
     })
}
```

Comment: delay operator will delays the api calls

Comment: Did you try ? I think delay delays value emission but not the api call

Comment: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/delay.html - for your reference